# El string que me retorna mi metodo lo asigno a un [value] y debo pasarlo a un [(ngModel)]

Tags: html5, angular

Tengo un metodo que guarda una imagen en el storage de firebase, este me retorma la url y la asigno a un [value] de esta manera:

```html
<div class="form-group">
                    <input 
                        type="text"
                        [value]="urlImage | async"
                        class="form-control"
                        name="avatar"
                        #avatar="ngModel"
                        [(ngModel)]="perfilService.seleccionarPerfil.avatar"
                        placeholder="Url">
```

pero el [(ngModel)] no acepta esta asignación, como podría pasarle el dato que traigo del value [] para que en [(ngModel)] me lo valide?

Comment: Qué hace perfilService.seleccionarPerfil.avatar? y qué error te da

Comment: perfilService.seleccionarPerfil.avatar debe asignar la url que me devuelve el método que sube la imagen a la base de datos, para guardarla asociada al objeto de cada perfil, el error que me sale es:                                           ERROR Error: Reference.push failed: first argument contains undefined in property 'perfiles.avatar'
    at validateFirebaseData (index.cjs.js:1442)
    at index.cjs.js:1489
    at each (index.cjs.js:544)
    at validateFirebaseData (index.cjs.js:1472)
    at validateFirebaseDataArg (index.cjs.js:1430)